# Android studio перечеркивает enableItemShiftingMode и enableShiftingMode

Tags: android, android-studio

Проблема показана на скрине. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Подскажите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Устаревший метод. В какой то из следующих версий андроид, его не будет.

Comment: И на что тогда мне его изменить можно?

Comment: Если для учебы, то ничего менять не надо. Неизвестно когда этот метод уберут. А так, глянь здесь, вроде есть ответ https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/issues/135